# Using __setattr__ method with getattr in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, getattr, setattr

I have a Python class as follows:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, response=20):
        self.response = response

    def func1(self):
       self.response = 10

    def func2(self):
        self.response = 20

    def func3(self):
        self.response = 30
```

Every time the value of response changes, I need it to be captured. So I defined a `__setattr__` method as follows:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, response=20):
        self.response = response

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'response':
            print('{} is set to {}'.format(name, value))

    def func1(self):
       self.response = 10

    def func2(self):
        self.response = 20

    def func3(self):
        self.response = 30
```

Output:

```
=============================================================
In [10]: a = Base()
response is set to 20

In [11]: a.func1()
response is set to 10

In [12]: a.func2()
response is set to 20
```

Works really well.

Now I introduced one more class attribute whose value is initialized by a dictionary lookup as follows:

```
my_dict = {20:'key1'}

class Base:
    def __init__(self, response=20):
        self.response = response
        self.key = getattr(my_dict,self.response).value

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'response':
            print('{} is set to {}'.format(name, value))

    def func1(self):
        self.response = 10

    def func2(self):
        self.response = 20

    def func3(self):
        self.response = 30
```

This gives an error stating:

```
 ----> 6         self.key = getattr(my_dict,self.response)
AttributeError: 'Base' object has no attribute 'response'
```

What am I doing wrong.Also if I remove the `__setattr__` method, the `getattr` starts working. What is the issue here?

Comment: Why not simply make it a property?

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: `my_dict = {20:'key1'}` has no attr `20` it is really so, it has key `20`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work

Comment: You never actually set any attributes. Your instances doesn't have a response attribute, you've intercepted that and simply printed a message. So `getattr(my_dict,self.response)` will fail, since `self.response` does not exist. Even if it *did*, you will fail with `getattr(my_dict, 20)`, since your dict doesn't have an attribute `20` (that's not really a valid attribute to access, so it just fails with a type error, since the argument to `setattr` and `getattr` must be `str` objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the parent implementation of __setattr__ to actually create the attribute:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == 'response':
        print('{} is set to {}'.format(name, value))
    super.__setattr__(self,name,value)
```

Also if you want the value associated with dictionary's key use :

```
self.key = my_dict.get(self.response)
```

You can find more details by looking at the official documentation [here(3.7)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=setattr#object.__setattr__)
and [here(2.7)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=setattr#object.__setattr__)

Comment: Pycharm gives this warning..Passing Base instead of super. Is this intentional? less... (⌘F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection checks for calls of a method by class while passing an instance of a different class as self parameter:
  foo = Foo()
  Bar.baz(foo, *more)
Sometimes this may be intentional and correct. But when unintentional, this leads to subtle bugs.   Is this fine ?